# Wonky Diagram with Drawing a Polygon - TiKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I am drawing polygons for fun, but I drew a 100-sided polygon, and the 100th and 1st points do not join up very well, and something seems amiss. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={200mm,237mm},
 left=5mm,
 top=30mm,
 }
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,amsmath} 
\usepackage[font=Large,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\large\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}\tkzDefPoint(0,9.5){1}
\tkzDefPointsBy[rotation=center O angle 3.6](1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99){2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100}
\tkzDrawPoints[fill =black,size=4,color=black](1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100)
\tkzDrawPolygon[thick](1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100)
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Hectogon/Hecatontagon/Hecatogon}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Could anyone please help? I attached a picture of the wonky part.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without digging through `tkz-euclide`'s manual I would just use a loop and polar coordinates:

```
\foreach \i in {0, ..., 99} {\tkzDefPoint(90+\i*3.6:9.5){\i}}
```

I've also added an alternative solution via TikZ's own [`graphs` libraries](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs).

They produce the same diagram.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\tikz
  \graph[
    edges=thick,
    nodes={circle, fill, draw, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+4pt},
    empty nodes
  ]{ subgraph C_n[n=100, counterclockwise, radius=9.5cm] };

\begin{tikzpicture}
% \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
\foreach \i in {0, ..., 99} {\tkzDefPoint(90+\i*3.6:9.5){\i}}
\tkzDrawPoints[fill=black, size=4pt, color=black](0,...,99)
\tkzDrawPolygon[thick](0,...,99)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here a solution with my next "tkz-elements" package. The beta version is ready, but I haven't finished the documentation yet. "tkz-elements" has been created precisely to overcome the problems associated with calculations. It's a Lua library that calculates the points required for the figure. You can then plot them either with TikZ or with tkz-euclide.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tkz-elements}
\begin{document}
 
 \begin{tkzelements}
   local r = 4
   max = 100
   for i = 1,max 
   do 
      z["A_"..i] = point : polar(r,2*i*math.pi/max)
   end
  set_lua_to_tex{"max"}
\end{tkzelements}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzGetNodes
\tkzDrawPolygon[thick,cyan](A_1,A_...,A_\max)
\tkzDrawPoints[color=black,size=1pt](A_1,A_...,A_\max)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The macro  `\tkzGetNodes` transforms the "z" table into nodes.
Among the problems I still have to solve is the function `set_lua_to_tex{"max"}`, which transforms the Lua variable "max" into a TeX macro `\max`.
is relatively dangerous because `\max` is global. Problems can arise with `alpha`, for example.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Let's have some fun! https://www.overleaf.com/read/qkctbkvntstv
PS: with `n=50`, TikZ throws some error, meanwhile Asymptote works with `n=10000` or more.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={n=25;},scale=5,c/.style={circle,fill=red,inner sep=3pt}]
\draw (0:1) node[c]{} 
\foreach \i[parse=true] in {1,...,(n)} 
        {--(\i*360/n:1) node[c]{}} --cycle;     
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{asy}
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
size(10cm);
int n=50;
pair[] points;
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
points.push(dir(360*i/n));
draw(operator--(...points)--cycle);
dot(points,blue+6pt);
//shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I found it a shame that your code with `Tikz` does not work beyond 45, we can swap the order of the calculations or use `\fp_eva`l, I was inspired by your code to propose a possibility.

Answer (score 6):

With the documentation of `tkz-euclide`, see the section `7.1.3. Polar coordinates`:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \an [count=\i] in {0,3.6,...,360}
        { \tkzDefPoint(\an:9.5){A_\i}}
    \tkzDrawPolygon[thick](A_1,A_...,A_100)
    \tkzDrawPoints[fill=black, size=4pt, color=black](A_1,A_...,A_100)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Another possibility from black Mild's code and with `fp_eval` from `Expl3`. There is no overflow even if you keep the multiplication first in `\i*360/100`. We can keep the `\foreach` command or use `\int_step_inline`.

I use parameters:

- #1 for the number of vertices,
  #2 for the radius
  #3 optional, for the position of the point name

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\tikzset{
  dot/.style = {
    circle,
    fill=#1,
    inner sep=1.5pt,
    outer sep=0pt,
  },
  dot/.default=red
}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\poly}{ m m O{} }
{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate  (P0) at (#2,0);
    \int_step_inline:nnn {1} {#1} 
      {
        \coordinate[dot=blue] (P##1) at 
          (\fp_eval:n { ##1*360/#1 } \tl_to_str:n { : } #2);
        \draw(P\fp_eval:n { ##1-1 }) -- (P##1);
      }
    %
    \tl_if_blank:nF {#3} 
      {
        \int_step_inline:nnn {1} {#1}
        {
          \path (0,0)--(P##1) node[pos=#3]{$M\c_math_subscript_token{##1}$};
        }
      }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\polyb}{ m m }
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (#2,0)
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}
    {
      --(\fp_eval:n { \i*360/#1 } \tl_to_str:n { : } #2) node[dot]{}
    }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%  blue with \int_step_inline
\poly{10}{3}[0.8]
\poly{20}{3}[1.2]
\poly{50}{3}
\poly{100}{3}
\poly{100}{9.5}[1.05]
%%%%%%%ùù red \foreach
\polyb{10}{3}
\polyb{20}{3}
\polyb{50}{3}
\polyb{100}{3}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

[image: The regular polygon with 120 vertices]

The drawing of the regular polygon with 120 vertices.  I used basic Tikz and the library `math` to have some constants (the radius of the circumscribed circle and the number of points).

**Remark** It works for big number of vertices, say 1000 or 2000 (see @Black Mild answer).

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[p/.style={%
    insert path={%
      node[circle, fill=black, inner sep=.7pt]{}
    }
  },
  evaluate={%
    integer \N; \N = 120;
    real \r; \r = 3;
  }]
  \draw[fill=orange!30] (0: \r) [p]
  \foreach \j in {1, ..., \N}{ -- (\j/\N*360: \r) [p] } -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's nice try to see how the `math` library increases the accuracy. It reminds me a remarkable post on this https://latex.net/tikzmath/